# How do I show my user created task which does not show up in Windows 2008 task scheduler?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, task-scheduler

From within "Task scheduler (local)", within the task scheduler application of Windows 2008 server, I have created a new task.

However the user created task doesn't show up in the list of "Active tasks". That list starts with entry "Database One Copy Alert".

#### Regression

- I know the tasks is there because creating another with exactly the same name results in an error message that there already exists a task with that name.
- It doesn't matter wether I create a "Basic task" or just a "Task".
- Ccleaner does show the user created task.
- Enable showing hidden tasks in Windows task scheduler doesn't improve.

How can I show the user created scheduled tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the left pane of the "Task scheduler" navigate to and **select** "Task Scheduler Library".

**Not the plus sign, the words themselves**, and you will see your custom scheduled tasks:

[image: Windows 2008 Task Scheduler with Task Scheduler Library selected]

Windows 7 also suffers from such a bizarre user interface design: https://superuser.com/questions/228235/windows-7-task-scheduler-doesnt-list-my-custom-tasks#answer-395085